# Messaging using Rhino Service Bus via MSMQ

Tags: rhino-servicebus

I'm just getting started with Rhino Service Bus and I'm trying to relay a message between 2 servers using MSMQ as the transport. For some reason the Rhino client does not receive the message when the backend/host is located on a different server, but works fine when located on the the same machine.

If I use Rhino queues instead of MSMQ as the transport then the message is sent across the servers.

I've even turned off the firewall. I've also made sure that the message end point is pointing to the right server, while the bus end point is always local.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a couple of reasons why the messages will not make it across a network to the other server. I would recommend you write a simple application to send a message to the other server. This will establish whether there is an issue with Rhino (which I doubt).

The other thing to check is whether the Distributed Transaction Controllers on the different machines can communicate. This is required to ensure transactional integrity of the messages. You can use [DTCPing](http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=2868) to test the DTC connection between the two servers.

I found this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/12/13/what-publically-available-tools-are-available-for-troubleshooting-msmq-problems.aspx) listing tools to use when debugging MSMQ issues. Some of the links are a bit old, but it seems useful.

Finally you can also try [MQPing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731852%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). It does not work in work group mode for MSMQ, but it might help.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a firewall issue. The ports of the service bus and client (specified in rhino.config) should be open. duh!